# UITableViewにUIPanGestureRecognizerを使ってもスクロールできなくならないようにしたい。

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitableview

`UITableView`にパンを認識させたいと思って`UIPanGestureRecognizer`を使ってみたのですが、それをしたらテーブルを上下にスクロールさせることができなくなってしまいました。

これを解消するためにGoogle検索をしたところ海外の質問に対する回答でで下のコードを記述すると良いと書いてありました。

```
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
　　if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: superview)
        if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

が、これをどこに書いたら良いのかわかりません。
いろいろなところに試してみましたが、うまくいきません。
そもそもこれでうまくいくのかどうかもわかりません。

どなたか教えてくださいませんか。

以下テーブルを作っている私のコードです

```
var table = UITableView()

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func equipList(_ notification: Notification) {

        //テーブル設定（省略）

        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self

        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan(_:)))
        pan.delegate = self
        table.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        self.view.addSubview(table)

    }

    @objc(tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        //セル設定（省略）

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }
}
```

これに

```
    extension UITableView {
        open override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            print(gestureRecognizer)
            if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
                let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: table)
                if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
                     print("A")
                    return true
                }
                print("B")
                return false
            }
            print("C")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

エラーが出なかったからこれかな？といった感じで記述してみたのですけれど、うまくいきません。
`gestureRecognizer`では`UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer`が呼ばれているようで。ちなみに全てBが返ってきて、スクロールはできません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension UITableView {
```

の中ではなく、

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

の中に定義するのではダメでしょうか？

イメージ的には

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: panGestureRecognizer.view)
            if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return false
    }

・・・
```

こういった感じです。

Comment: できました！ overrideはつけないのですね。そのせいでエラーが出てここには記述できないものだと思っていました...。ありがとうございました。